Find the limit $\lim_{{x \to \infty}} \left( \sin(\sqrt{x+1}) - \sin(\sqrt{x}) \right)$
I'm working through Advanced Calculus: Theory and Practice by John S. Petrovic and is currently working on problem 3.5.9, which is as follows:
Find the limit and give a strict “ε − δ” proof that the result is
correct:
$\lim_{{x \to \infty}} \left( \sin(\sqrt{x+1}) - \sin(\sqrt{x}) \right)$
There are other threads which discuss the topic around finding the limit of the function ($\lim_{{x \to \infty}} \left( \sin(\sqrt{x+1}) - \sin(\sqrt{x}) \right)$), but do not supply a epsilon-delta proof that it is correct. Also, I have a particular question regarding the solution to this limit (I'll get to that).
The most straight forward solution to $\lim_{{x \to \infty}} \left( \sin(\sqrt{x+1}) - \sin(\sqrt{x}) \right)$ that I can find (and understand) goes like this:
Note, $\sin(a) - \sin(b) = 2\cos(\frac{a+b}{2})\sin(\frac{a-b}{2})$, therefore:
$\sin(\sqrt{x+1}) - \sin(\sqrt{x}) = 2\cos(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}{2})\sin(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}}{2})=$
$2\cos(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}{2})\sin(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}}{2}\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}})=$
$2\cos(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}{2})\sin(\frac{1}{2(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x})})$.
At this stage the argument I find is this (which I'm doubtful of), because:
$\lim_{{x \to \infty}} \sin\frac{1}{2(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x})}=0 \implies$
$\lim_{{x \to \infty}} 2\cos(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}{2})\sin(\frac{1}{2(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x})})=0$, however does that really make sense?
Using $\lim_{{x \to \infty}} \sin\frac{1}{2(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x})}=0$ imply that $\lim_{{x \to \infty}} 2\cos(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}{2})\sin(\frac{1}{2(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x})})=$
$\lim_{{x \to \infty}} 2 \cdot\lim_{{x \to \infty}} \cos(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}{2}) \cdot \lim_{{x \to \infty}} \sin(\frac{1}{2(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x})})$. But $\lim_{{x \to \infty}} \cos(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}{2})$ does not exists since $\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \cos(2n\pi)=1 \neq \lim_{{n \to \infty}} \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi)=0$.
So my reasoning is that according to the field axioms $0$ multiplied with any number equals $0$, but $0$ multiplied with something undefined is not equal to $0$. Therefore we must rely on the Squeeze theorem.
$-2\sin(\frac{1}{2(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x})}) \leq 2\cos(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}{2})\sin(\frac{1}{2(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x})}) \leq 2\sin(\frac{1}{2(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x})})$, where:

$\lim_{{x \to \infty}} -2\sin(\frac{1}{2(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x})}) = 0$

$\lim_{{x \to \infty}} 2\sin(\frac{1}{2(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x})}) = 0$


And therefore we have that $\lim_{{x \to \infty}} 2\cos(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}{2})\sin(\frac{1}{2(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x})})=0$
Does my argument make sense or is it unnecessary to use the Squeeze theorem here?
Now, could someone please help explain to me how I define $M$ as an expression of $\epsilon$ so that I can make an "epsilon-delta" proof of the kind:
For each $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $M=...>0$ such that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $x>M$.
Thank you.

You are right that you have to use the squeeze theorem. Actually, there is a special case of it that you could use: if $f$ is bounded in some deleted neighborhood of $a$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x)=0$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)g(x)=0$. In your case, $\cos(\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}}{2})$ is bounded.

In any case, in the link you posted, there is a more simple proof using the mean value theorem (instead of using trigonometric identities), which gives a specific upper bound for $|\sin(\sqrt{x+1})=\sin(\sqrt{x})|$. You can use it to construct an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof.

I don't see why you have to avoid squeeze theorem because the squeeze theorem itself is an $\epsilon - \delta$ proof and you can just embed its proof into your theorem.

Hint for your final question: $ |\sin u|\le|u|$.

It's easier to just use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-criterion directly:
Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary, then due to uniform continuity of $x\longmapsto\sin x$, there exists a $\delta>0$ with
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
|x-y|<\delta\Longrightarrow |\sin x - \sin y|<\varepsilon.
\end{equation}
Then, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $x>\frac{1}{\delta^2}$, we have
\begin{equation}
|\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}<\delta.
\end{equation}
So by $(1)$, we immediately get $$ \forall x\in \mathbb{R} : x >\frac{1}{\delta^2}\Longrightarrow |\sin(\sqrt{x+1})-\sin(\sqrt{x})|<\varepsilon,$$
and since $\varepsilon>0$ was chosen arbitrarily, this means that $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sin(\sqrt{x+1})-\sin(\sqrt{x})=0.$$
